# usb 2-1.6: cannotsubmit urb 0, error -28: not enought bandwidth

Tags: boot, usb, updates, bandwidth

Afther an updated to 6.5.0-14, i can start ubuntu, i have the error "usb 2-1.6: cannotsubmit urb 0, error -28: not enought bandwidth" at initial screen.
I have try to start in recovery mode with a previous version 6.2.0-39 and runs correctly.

Is there any solution or a way to back to the previous version?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, it's about the nvidia drivers, i have removed the nvidia drivers and the linux starts again but i can't find the good versio for the nvidia drivers, all the versions crash my computer.